# How do I install MySQL workbench?

Tags: installation, 9.10, mysql

I am using **Ubuntu 9.10 - the Karmic Koala** - released in October 2009

I downloaded **mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1004-i386.deb** from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads)

But when I run this package it show me following error:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.29.3)
```

I am new to ubuntu. I have tried many packages but unable to install MySQL Workbench. How can I install it on my ubuntu...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't upgrade to a newer Ubuntu (e.g. 10.10), you can grab an older version of mysql-workbench. It looks like http://download.softagency.net/mysql/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/ has a listing of older versions. [This](http://technopaper.blogspot.com/2009/12/installing-mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu.html) suggests that mysql-workbench-oss-5.1.18a-1ubu904-i386.deb may work.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to using an old release of Ubuntu.

I was able to install MySQL workbench on Ubuntu 2010.10

Can you consider upgrading to the latest Ubuntu first?

Comment: According to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com), libatk1.0-0 is at version 1.28 in Karmic and 1.30 in Lucid, and there's no backport of that package. So there's no pre-built package available.

Answer (score 0):

To install Workbench go to terminal(ctrl + alt + T) and type following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:olivier-berten/misc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
mysql-workbench &
```

[install-mysql-workbench-ubuntu](http://webrewrite.com/install-mysql-workbench-ubuntu/)